# Mool mantra Vs Astothram

Tags: ganesha

Usually we chant ashtotram.during functions like Vinayak charthurthi, saraswathi Pooja etc , but recently my in laws were there during Vinayak charthurthi and he was of the opinion that ganaoathi moola mantra can be chanted instead of Astothram (maybe because it is difficult to get the pronounciation right ). He opined that nothing bigger than moola mantra and repeating it is enough. However usually sankalpa I do is for Astothram..can some explain difference between two and in which occasions the two should be used or can it be used as per convenience and belief.

Comment: Both can be chanted.. thr are no scriptural injunctions regarding this ... Traditionally what is done is like this - a Puja+Mula Mantra Japa+  Stotra Parayana (108/1008 names etc)..